# I am not able to print the complete table in pdf using latex documentation tool and I am not able to draw a horizontal line

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c p{8cm} |c p{5cm} |c|}
            \hline
            \textbf{QUALIFICATION} & \textbf{INSTITUTION} & \textbf{UNIVERSITY/BOARD} & 
            \textbf{ACADEMIC-YEAR} & \textbf{PERCENTAGE \%}\\ \hline \hline
            \textbf{B-TECH CSE} & ELURU COLLEGE OF ENGINEERING \& TECHNOLOGY (ELURU) A.P & JNTU KAKINADA & 2016 - 20 & 76.36\%\\ \hline
            \textbf{INTERMEDIATE} & SRI CHAITANYA JUNIOR COLLEGE (ELURU) A.P & BOARD OF INTERMEDIATE & 2014  - 16 & 92.6\%\\ \hline
            \textbf{10$^t$$^h$ CLASS} & ZPHS MAHADEVAPALLI,ELURU & SCHOOL OF SECONDARY EDUCATION & 2013 -2014 & 7.2\% \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
```

Comment: Please always provide a full but minimal example that others can copy as it and compile it like you compile it at your end. Here we have no idea what class or preamble you are using.

Comment: Additionally you should probably try to explain you problem, perhaps add an image in the body of your quesiton instead of in the title. I have no idea what you mean by "using latex documentation tool". If I add the example to a simple document it compiles fine, but you have too much text for it to fit within the size of the text. You might want to have a look at the `c` columns and perhaps make then `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4cm}` or similar (assumes the `array` package)

Answer (score 1):

Too much width. Shrinking the text or columns, or removing some text might help.

[image: table test]

Example of using `array` package to specify the `>{...}` column formatting.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{array}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}[Scale=0.8]
\begin{document}
%\small
\begin{tabular}{c>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}cr}
            \hline
            \textbf{QUALIFICATION} & 
            \textbf{INSTITUTION} & 
            \textbf{UNIVERSITY/BOARD} & 
            \textbf{YEAR} & 
            \textbf{\%}\\ 
            \hline \hline
            \textbf{B-TECH CSE} & 
            ELURU COLLEGE OF ENGINEERING \& TECHNOLOGY (ELURU) A.P & 
            JNTU KAKINADA & 
            2016 - 20 & 
            76.36\%\\ 
            \hline
            \textbf{INTERMEDIATE} & SRI CHAITANYA JUNIOR COLLEGE (ELURU) A.P & BOARD OF INTERMEDIATE & 2014  - 16 & 92.6\%\\ \hline
            \textbf{10\textsuperscript{th} CLASS} & ZPHS MAHADEVAPALLI,ELURU & SCHOOL OF SECONDARY EDUCATION & 2013 -2014 & 7.2\% \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```